# How requestLocationUpdates() works

Tags: android-location

1. where I need to call the `requestLocationUpdates()` function, whether it is activity or application
2. If we call `requestLocationUpdates()` too many times what will happen ? 
   Will it overwrite the previous one or it will make one more request ?
3. I need request for location update for both gps and network, what I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `Activity` mainly, I haven't seen anyone calling it in an `Application`. Anyway I think you're also able to call it from an `Application`, because you have access to a `Context` there.
2. Nothing special, I think it might **DRAIN BATTERY** and also is not usable, I suggest using `requestSingleUpdate()` method if you want to  call it too many times. No, it will not overwrite, I haven't seen it neither in action nor in the `LocationManager` documents.
3. From the [documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html):

   > You can also request location updates from both the GPS and the Network Location Provider by calling requestLocationUpdates() twice—once for NETWORK_PROVIDER and once for GPS_PROVIDER.